# Reference request: Basic properties of the category of small categories with finite products and finite product perserving functors.

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

Let $ \mathbf{Fp} $ be the category whose objects are all small categories with finite products (by which I mean for any two objects $ c_1, c_2 \in \mathbf{C}$, we have a designated product $c_1 \times c_2 $ of $ c_1$ and $c_2$ and a specified $0$-ary product $1$.) and whose morphisms are the finite product preserving functors. (That is, the functor $F \colon \mathbf{C} \to \mathbf{D}$ is a morphism between $ \mathbf{C} $ and $ \mathbf{D} $ just in case, for every product diagram $ (c,p \colon c \to c_1,q \colon c \to c_2)$ in $ \mathbf{C} $, $(Fc, Fp, Fq) $ is a product diagram of $Fc_1$ and $ Fc_2$ in $\mathbf{D}$. (Does this category go by another name than $\mathbf{Fp}$?)

I was looking for any references which cover the ``basic properties'' of $ \mathbf{Fp} $.  For example, I would be interested in reading about any attempts at characterizing the various morphisms in $\mathbf{Fp} $. (I saw this addressed for monomorphisms in $\mathbf{Cat}$ in another Stack Exchange post).

Thank you very much for your consideration.

Comment: I don't have a reference to provide but I'd be interested in knowing what properties are you looking to characterize.

Comment: Typically, when people refer to products with finite products, they also include 0-ary products (aka the terminal object).

Comment: Your terminology is not standard. Finite products include, well, all finite products, not just binary products. Finite products can be reduced to binary products and terminal objects.

Comment: Also, can you please focus your question? What properties are you interested in exactly? And what types of morphisms would you like to understand? And, perhaps more important: what is the motivation for the question? This would help a lot to give the best answers for you.

Comment: Thank you Mark Saving, in my comment about that there are canonical products, I forgot to mention the designated $0$-ary product. Does this clarify the confusion about binary products and finary products? I am aware if you have a 0-ary product and binary products, you have finary products and vice versa.